# Is it possiable to communicate PayPal Virtual Terminal with Magento

Tags: magento, paypal

Is there a way to see if we can get that to communicate PayPal Virtual Terminal with Magento.

so that once the **payment has been made in PayPal virtual Terminal it will automatically update the order using the order number as a reference**?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the IPN (Instant Payment Notification) options available in the account? For all transactions (including virtual terminal) done on paypal.com an IPN (Instant Payment Notification) will be generated if set.

You can consume this IPN in your mangento implementation and process it accordingly.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/